# Copy Data of All Files in a Folder and Make a Master Sheet in Excel For Analysis

Tags: excel, vba

Hy!

**Problem Description:**
    I have multiple workbooks in my Data Folder. I have written a Macro that is copying data from all the files But it skipping the first Sheet Tab data in every workbook and start copy data from 2nd Sheet Tab. I want you to review my code and guide me where I am missing. 
**Problem Statement**

Macro is Working Perfect but it mises the First Sheet tab in every workbook and start copy data from second sheet tab. It shold start copy data from first sheet tab.

**The macro is as under.**

```
Sub CopWKBooksInFolder() 'Test and worked fine macro
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim myfolder As String
    Dim Str As String
    Dim a As Single
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    Set WS = Sheets.Add

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Show
        myfolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With
    chk = 0
    Value = Dir(myfolder)
    Do Until Value = ""
        If Value = "." Or Value = ".." Then
        Else
            If Right(Value, 3) = "xls" Or Right(Value, 4) = "xlsx" Or Right(Value, 4) = "xlsm" Then
                On Error Resume Next
                Workbooks.Open FileName:=myfolder & Value, Password:="zzzzzzzzzzzz"
                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                Else
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
                        If sht.Range("A1") <> "" Then
                            lRow = WS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                            If chk = 0 Then
                                sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy Destination:=WS.Range("A" & lRow)
                                chk = 1
                            Else
                                Set crng = sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
                                Set crng = crng.Offset(1, 0)
                                Set crng = crng.Resize(crng.Rows.Count - 1)
                                crng.Copy Destination:=WS.Range("A" & lRow)
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next sht
                End If
                Workbooks(Value).Close False
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        End If
        Value = Dir
    Loop
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End Sub
```

Comment: You've got a `For Each` loop so it shouldn't be skipping the first sheet. Is it possible that `If sht.Range("A1") <> "" Then` is not true for the first sheet?

Comment: Your code looks at every single Worksheet in every single Workbook, and copying  even works on the very first Worksheet, but from the second Worksheet it only copies data starting with the second Row.

Comment: Is that what you wanted to say in your post?

Comment: @AndrasDorko Yes

Comment: Shakeel, it is perfectly fine if you didn't like my edit, but if you say "Sheet Tab" in your problem description, then people will think you are talking about Worksheets being skipped.. I thought you agreed above to my description of your problem. First Data Row of every Worksheet from the Second Worksheet are what is skipped not Worksheets.

Comment: What are you calling "Sheet Tab" ??

Comment: See even @BigBen above, thought you were saying that your code skipped Worksheets... You are misleading people with "Sheet Tab".

Comment: Anyway try my Answer, I think you'll get what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Referring back to our conversation in the comments:

> Your code looks at every single Worksheet in every single Workbook, and copying even works on the very first Worksheet, but from the second Worksheet it only copies data starting with the second Row. – **Andras Dorko**
>
> Is that what you wanted to say in your post? – **Andras Dorko**
>
> @AndrasDorko Yes – **shakeel ahmad**

The reason why the above happens is this:

To start with, `chk = 0` and therefore, the first section of your IF block is executed:

```
If chk = 0 Then
    sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy Destination:=WS.Range("A" & lRow)
    chk = 1
Else
    Set crng = sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Set crng = crng.Offset(1, 0)
    Set crng = crng.Resize(crng.Rows.Count - 1)
    crng.Copy Destination:=WS.Range("A" & lRow)
End If
```

... copying data properly into your the second line of your new Worksheet.

But because of the above `chk = 1` as this was in the first part of the IF block.

When processing comes back to this same IF block at the time of looking into second Worksheet, only ELSE section can be processed because of `chk = 1`.

The ELSE section of the IF block has two lines in it which causes your problem:

```
Set crng = crng.Offset(1, 0)
Set crng = crng.Resize(crng.Rows.Count - 1)
```

The first line shifts the range to be copied down by one row.
Meaning, the first line of the original range to be copied is removed, the new range 
starts on the second line, but because the size of the range hasn't changed there will be an empty line shifted into the range after the last real datarow.

Your second line actually removes that blank line from the new range.

So effectively you, by the above two lines removed the first line of data found in the Worksheet, and only the rest gets copied over into the new Worksheet.

I am not sure why you needed `chk` either.

I think your code would do exactly as you wanted if the IF block was removed and you only kept this line of it:

```
sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy Destination:=WS.Range("A" & lRow)
```

Effectively removing the IF block althogether apart from the line above.

It works for me.. try it.

This is what the whole code block would look like:

```
Sub CopWKBooksInFolder() 'Test and worked fine macro
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim myfolder As String
    Dim Str As String
    Dim a As Single
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    Set WS = Sheets.Add

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Show
        myfolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

    Value = Dir(myfolder)
    Do Until Value = ""
        If Value = "." Or Value = ".." Then
        Else
            If Right(Value, 3) = "xls" Or Right(Value, 4) = "xlsx" Or Right(Value, 4) = "xlsm" Then
                On Error Resume Next
                Workbooks.Open FileName:=myfolder & Value, Password:="zzzzzzzzzzzz"
                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                Else
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
                        If sht.Range("A1") <> "" Then
                            lRow = WS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                            sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy Destination:=WS.Range("A" & lRow)
                        End If
                    Next sht
                End If
                Workbooks(Value).Close False
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        End If
        Value = Dir
    Loop
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so you mean I need to remove the additional Else Statement and chk part of if. Right

Comment: I have actually re-edited my answer, sorry... It would have worked that way as well but there is absolutely no need to keep `If chk = 0 Then` either...

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just copy and paste this code then test but the problem is still there.

Comment: When did you copy it?

Comment: Do you still have the same problem? @shakeel ahmad